# Variable Scope Issue in Python

Tags: python, recursion, call, callstack

I am new to Python and I have been working with it for a bit, but I am stuck on a problem. Here is my code:

```
def collatz(num,ctr):
    if(num != 1):
        ctr+=1
        if(num%2==0):
            collatz(num/2,ctr)
        else:
            collatz(num*3+1,ctr)
    return ctr
test=collatz(9,0)
```

For any number I put in for `num`, let's say `9` for instance, and `0` for `ctr`, `ctr` always comes out as `1`. Am I using the `ctr` variable wrong?

EDIT:
I am trying to print out how many times the function is recursed. So `ctr` would be a counter for each recursion.

Comment: what is the intended result and what you want to achieve with this?

Comment: `ctr = collatz(num//2, ctr)`. Also you should be working with Python 3, and `/ 2` is floating point division, `// 2` is integer division.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variable `ctr` in your example will always be `1` because of the order of the recursive call stack. As one value of `ctr` is returned, then the call stack will start returning the previous values of `ctr`. Basically, at the very last recursive call, the highest value of `ctr` will be returned. But since the method call at the bottom of the call stack returns the very last value aka the value that will be stored in `test`, `test` will always be `1`. Let's say I input parameters into `collatz` that would result in five total calls of the method. The call stack would look like this coming down,

```
collatz returns ctr --> 5
collatz returns ctr --> 4
collatz returns ctr --> 3
collatz returns ctr --> 2
collatz returns ctr --> 1 //what matters because ctr is being returned with every method call
```

As you can see, no matter how many times `collatz` is called, `1` will always be returned because the call at the bottom of the call stack has `ctr` equaling `1`.

The solution can be a lot of things, but it really depends on the purpose of what you're trying to accomplish which isn't clearly stated in your question.

EDIT: If you want `ctr` to end up being the number of times a recursive call is made, then just assign `ctr` to the value of the method call. It should look like this,

```
def collatz(num,ctr):
    if(num != 1):
        ctr+=1
        if(num%2==0):
            ctr = collatz(num/2,ctr)
        else:
            ttr = collatz(num*3+1,ctr)
    return ctr
test=collatz(9,0)
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation of how the recursion works. I understand that a lot better now. I wasn't very good with explaining what I wanted in the final result so I will edit the question.

Comment: @Webtron check my edit out because I think it should address your result now.

Answer (score 4):

I changed your recursive calls to set the value received back from the recursive calls into ctr. The way you wrote it, you were discarding the values you got back from recursing.

```
def collatz(num,ctr):
    if(num != 1):
            ctr+=1
            if(num%2==0):
                    ctr=collatz(num/2,ctr)
            else:
                    ctr=collatz(num*3+1,ctr)
    return ctr

test=collatz(9,0)
```

Comment: this is the same, what's the difference?

Comment: I changed your recursive calls to set the value received back from the recursive calls into `ctr`. The way you wrote it, you were discarding the values you got back from recursing.

Comment: You should explain that in the answer, not simply give the code

Answer (score 0):

An example:

```
def collatz(number):

    if number % 2 == 0:
        print(number // 2)
        return number // 2

    elif number % 2 == 1:
        result = 3 * number + 1
        print(result)
        return result

n = input("Give me a number: ")
while n != 1:
    n = collatz(int(n))
```

Comment: Not exactly what the asker is looking for. His function is trying to count how many times it has to run before the number it reaches 1.

Answer (score 0):

Function parameters in Python are passed by value, not by reference. If you pass a number to a function, the function receives a copy of that number. If the function modifies its parameter, that change will not be visible outside the function:

```
def foo(y):
   y += 1
   print("y=", y) # prints 11

x = 10
foo(x)
print("x=", x) # Still 10
```

In your case, the most direct fix is to make ctr into a global variable. Its very ugly because you need to reset the global back to 0 if you want to call the collatz function again but I'm showing this alternative just to show that your logic is correct except for the pass-by-reference bit. (Note that the collatz function doesn't return anything now, the answer is in the global variable).

```
ctr = 0
def collatz(num):
    global ctr
    if(num != 1):
        ctr+=1
        if(num%2==0):
                collatz(num/2)
        else:
                collatz(num*3+1)

ctr = 0
collatz(9)
print(ctr)
```

Since Python doesn't have tail-call-optimization, your current recursive code will crash with a stack overflow if the collatz sequence is longer than 1000 steps (this is Pythons default stack limit). You can avoid this problem by using a loop instead of recursion. This also lets use get rid of that troublesome global variable. The final result is a bit more idiomatic Python, in my opinion:

```
def collats(num):
    ctr = 0
    while num != 1:
        ctr += 1
        if num % 2 == 0:
            num = num/2
         else:
            num = 3*num + 1
    return ctr

print(collatz(9))
```

If you want to stick with using recursive functions, its usually cleaner to avoid using mutable assignment like you are trying to do. Instead of functions being "subroutines" that modify state, make them into something closer to mathematical functions, which receive a value and return a result that depends only on the inputs. It can be much easier to reason about recursion if you do this. I will leave this as an exercise but the typical "skeleton" of a recursive function is to have an if statement that checks for the base case and the recursive cases:

```
def collatz(n):
    if n == 1:
        return 0
    else if n % 2 == 0:
        # tip: something involving collatz(n/2)
        return #??? 
    else:
        # tip: something involving collatz(3*n+1)
        return #???
```

Answer (score -3):

The variable will return the final number of the collatz sequence starting from whatever number you put in. The collatz conjecture says this will always be 1

Comment: Mathematically, yes, but that is not the reason this method does return 1

Comment: The function is supposed to return the number of steps to *reach* 1.